# Narration from 'Animal Kingdom'

Tags: dialogue, animal-kingdom-2010

I'm trying to remember a quote from the Australian crime movie [Animal Kingdom](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1313092/), which I don't have a copy of to hand. It's where the narrator (Joshua) is describing/introducing Craig - he says something to the effect of 'He lived like there was always something just in front of him, just out of reach.' I'm trying to find out exactly what it was because it's a brilliant quote - if anyone could help me out with the wording, and maybe point me in the direction of a source, I would be very grateful! Cheers

Comment: Not sure if this is a fit here as this is basically a "Identify-this-dialogue"

Comment: @AnkitSharma before introducing a new tag I would have waited if `identify-this-dialogue` is actually decided to be on-topic in the first place. Next we get `identify-this-best-actor-in-a-columbus-movie-award-winner`.

Comment: @ChristianRau previously it holds completely wrong tag, so i changed it per the question. If their is any issue you can rollback it.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Well Ok, the previous tag was really wrong. I guess we can just keep `identify-this-dialogue` for now and see how the question develops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"My Uncle Craig moved really fast, Like... he was tryin' to stay in front of somthin'"  - according to [imdb quotes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1313092/trivia?tab=qt). Part of this longer quote:

> Mum kept me away from her family because she was scared. I didn't
>   realise it at the time - but they were all scared, Even if they didn't
>   show it. I think even Barry Brown was scared - even though he never
>   showed it, Everyone felt safe around Baz', He'd punch your head off if
>   ya got in the way, If he was in the middle of an armed robbin', He'd
>   put you on the floor and not think twice about it, But he was good to
>   me - and to everyone else, Darren was only a couple of years older
>   than me, When we were little kids, he was like, my best friend, We
>   used to throw rocks at cars 'n' that, He had a way better BMX than me
>   - my bike was shit. My Uncle Craig moved really fast, Like... he was tryin' to stay in front of somthin', And Gramda Smurf, She just seemed
>   to wanna be where ever the boys were, And she just wanted to be around
>   what ever the boys were doing. But they were all scared, Even if they
>   didn't show it, Even if they didn't know it exactly, Even if they were
>   having to do what - crooks do all the time which is, Block out the
>   thing they must know, They must know it, Which is why crooks always
>   come undone, Always, One way or another, In Melbourne at this time,
>   This is a while ago now, The armed robbery mob was out of control,
>   They were shooting guys willy-nilly and gettin' away with it, And,
>   they'd been after Baz and my family for months, But the guy they
>   really wanted, The guy they really hated, Was my other Uncle - Uncle
>   Andrew, But everyone just called him 'Pope', He was hiding in a motel
>   room somewhere 'cause, He heard he was next, Craig was sellin' drugs,
>   He was sellin' lots of 'em, He had a detective in the drug squad
>   helpin' him do it, A guy called 'Randall Roach', They meet in a fish
>   shop in Footsgray, 'Cause Craig loved fish, An' I dunno - all this
>   seemed strange to me, but not strange either, You know what I mean?
>   Kids just are where ever they are, And they just do what ever they're
>   doin', You know? this is where I was, And this is what I was doin',
>   After my mum died, this is just the world I got thrown into.